# It is possible to review a Person with structured data?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets

I have review data centered around [people](https://schema.org/Person).

I would like to represent these reviews with structured data.

Something like this: ([from here](http://moz.com/ugc/getting-the-most-out-of-schemaorg-microformats))

[image]

This is what I tried: (It's a variation of the Google's Book example [here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#marking_up_an_aggregate_rating))

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <h2>
    <span itemprop="honorificPrefix">Dr</span>
    <span itemprop="name">Joe Smith</span>
  </h2>
  <h3 itemprop="jobTitle">Doctor</h3>
  <div itemprop="description">Extra super Doctor</div>
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <div>Doctor rating:
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">88</span> out of 
      <span itemprop="bestRating">100</span> with
      <span itemprop="ratingCount">20</span> ratings
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when I test this code in [Google's testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), I get the error:

> The property aggregateRating is not recognized by Google for an object
>   of type Person.

So does this mean that there is there no way to rate people with structured data?

Comment: Is there something wrong with this question? I'd appreciate an answer even if it's obvious because I'm new to structured data, and after googling I couldn't find relevant information. My understanding is that this question is on-topic because of all the in-use tags which seem to have drawn hundreds of questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`aggregateRating` property](http://schema.org/aggregateRating) is only defined for `CreativeWork`/`Offer`/`Organization`/`Place`/`Product`, but not for `Person`.

Alternatives:

- [`AggregateRating`](http://schema.org/AggregateRating) defines the [`itemReviewed` property](http://schema.org/itemReviewed), which expects a `Thing` as value, so it can be used with `Person`:

  `AggregateRating` → `itemReviewed` → `Person`
- You might also want to consider if it’s really the person that gets rated here, and not something that this person offers (i.e., a service like a medical examination):

  `Person` → [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) → `Offer`
  `Offer` → [`aggregateRating`](http://schema.org/aggregateRating) → `AggregateRating`

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, but I'm still confused. Perhaps I generalized this question too much. In my case I have data where students anonymously grade/review their professors. There is a rating for individual teaching characteristics, and an average rating score. ([image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51558405/gb.PNG)) I tried your first workaround, ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/a9jtd39v/)) but it seems that I still have to embed the AggregateRating in a valid schema.org type which kind of doesn't make sense here. I'd really appreciate your help here. Thanks again.

Comment: @Danield: Except for the `itemprop="aggregateRating"` (which you should omit), the markup in your fiddle is correct Microdata and an appropriate use of the Schema.org vocabulary. The error that Google’s Testing Tool reports seems to be a bug on their side, I guess. [According to their documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews), they should support this `itemReviewed` way. (By the way, Google seems to require `worstRating`, but this is not related to the reported error.)

Comment: @Danield: However, according to your use case, I’d say it’s not the *person* that gets rated, but the person’s performance/job/skills/service (whatever you may call it). If that’s correct, you could use [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) (and its [`aggregateRating`](http://schema.org/aggregateRating) property) instead. Or maybe [`EducationEvent`](http://schema.org/EducationEvent) (in combination with `itemReviewed`), if the ratings are for a specific course.

Answer (score 0):

You also might try using an RDFa document, set the foaf and schema prefixes and URIs, and then use schema:ratingValue as a property of the about="person". Google definitely will validate this approach on their testing site. However, I'm uncertain if and how it would appear in a Google search.